# Mongo C++ driver Ver 3.3.1 and Mongo C Driver compatibility?

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

The [page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases/tag/r3.3.1) about the latest version of C++ Driver says:

```
Please note that this version of mongocxx requires the MongoDB C driver 1.10.1.
```

Should I get this literally? I'm asking because the latest version of C Driver is 1.13.0... should I rollback to 1.10.1?

Comment: No, you should definitely be able to use 1.13.x. That is a minimum requirement, not an exact requirement.